# avoiding duplication with data objects

Tags: java, spring, web-services, architecture

We have a service which produces dozens of various response beans.  They are used by other services inside the application.  There is also a web service which exposes parts of the same functionality.  It returns response objects which pretty much correspond 1:1 to the internal response beans.  Of course they are not identical: some fields are removed, swagger documentation attributes are added etc.

Reusing the same beans feels impossible, they are different enough and even if there were only slightly different, mixing them together feel bad because one is internal and the other is exposed.  Also there is this dream of developing this in modern micro-services type of way where components are modularized and independent.

Not reusing means essentially duplicating every response object, creating converters, keeping both in sync.

Both ways suck and I can't think of anything good.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

I've been here quite often.  There are tools to make the mappers easier (bean-mappers and what not), but they usually introduce far more bugs than not.  I've also seen/tried inheritance schemes, having one domain object inherit from the other... That once again usually causes more problems than it solves.

It turns out that 90% of the time, you have different concerns for your internal vs your external representation of data.  And a mapping layer is a great place to keep those concerns separate.  Combining them always burns me further down the road.   Your mileage may vary, but I doubt it will, unless you have the most simple of apps, you will need to have separate objects.

It's boring code, but it's simple, and very easily testable.  Once you do it, your encapsulation goes way up, and you are able to allow your contract to change independent of your internal implementation.